# How to send response dynamically from springMVC controller?

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

How can i send object of ModelAndView if validation is successful and JSON(holding error messages) if it is not successful.

I am using springMVC(annotation)

If case if the validation is successful the signature is like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/chitchat", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addNewChat(@ModelAttribute("chat") Chat chat , HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Errors errors) {
```

If case if the validation fails i have to follow the signature like this

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/chitchat", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addNewChat(@ModelAttribute("chat") Chat chat , HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Errors errors) {
```

I am calling this functionality using **AJAX**.

What should be the best practice to fix this issue ?

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to do that. Return JSON if the user asked for a JSON response, but otherwise render a human-friendly error page.

Comment: If the only need to list error messages in case of validation failure, why don't you use native spring binding form? Pure JSON there's not needed. There's `<spring:errors>` tag for this.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i am using ajax. Just now i updated my question.
@WildDev <spring:errors> will not be understood by jquery

Comment: @chrylis I am using ajax so i want that error should be in json format. so that i can parse it.

Comment: Then you have to redirect the user using javascript possibilities rather than Spring's

Comment: @WildDev As i said i am using ajax I don't want to redirect. On the same page i want the updated object to be rendered.

Comment: It's about Javascript, it's the only way to render the new state of your object without page reloading. Swap the return value of your `@ResponseBody` method with an extended object you want to modify that contains the error list and handle this on JS side.